# Difference Between *(Pointer + Index) and Pointer[]

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int* myPointer = new int[100];

// ...

int firstValue = *(myPointer + 0);
int secondValue = myPointer[1];
```

Is there any functional difference between `*(myPointer + index)` and `myPointer[index]`?  Which is considered better practice?

Comment: You forgot: `int thirdValue = 2[myPointer];` Which crazily also works.

Comment: @Martin Really?  Huh.  Learn something new every day, I guess.

Comment: @Maxpm - [Array subscripting is commutative in C](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html)

Comment: There is no difference. `array[index]` and `index[array]` are just syntax sugar for `*(array + index)`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Functionally, they are identical.

Semantically, the pointer dereference says "Here's a thing, but I really care about the thing `X` spaces over", while the array access says "Here's a bunch of things, I care about the `Xth` one."

In most cases, I would prefer the array form.

Comment: Someone voted this down? I wish people would comment, and tell me what is wrong with my answer.

Comment: Wasn't me, but in this case it's not the `Xth` but the `X+1th`.

Comment: @Fritschy: Well, as programmers, I assume we count from 0 ;)

Comment: Let's not start a flame war, shall we :)

Comment: +1 for the semantics, great summary. I'm often tempted to use `*(p + offset)` whenever I have a pointer, for some idea of consistency (vs 'actual' arrays), but in practical terms I find `p[offset]` looks better and more intuitive in most cases, relegating the `+` form to 'offset from this other thing'.

Answer (score 39):

There is no difference between

```
*(array+10); //and
array[10];
```

but guess what? since `+` is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition#Commutativity)

```
 *(10 + array); //is all the same
 10[array]; //! it's true try it !
```

Comment: This is true because `+` is commutative. Operation `+` is also associative, but this isn't important here.

Answer (score 15):

No, they are functionally equivalent.

First, `index` is scaled up to the type size then added to the `myPointer` base, then the value is extracted from that memory location.

The "better practice" is the more readable one, which is usually, but not necessarily always, the `myPointer[index]` variant.

That's because you're usually interested in an element of the array, not the memory location to dereference.

Answer (score 6):

There is no functional difference I know of but the form `myPointer[1]` is ultimately more readable and far less likely to incur coding errors.

DC

The form `*(myPointer + 1)` does not allow for changing the type of pointer to an object and therefore getting access to the overloaded [] operator.

Also debugging is far harder

```
 int *ints[10];
 int myint = ints[10];
```

is easier to pickup visually than

```
 int *ints;
 int myint = *(ints + 10);
```

also the compiler can insert range checking to catch the error at compile time.

DC

Comment: But when you need the address, the form `ints + 10` is better than `&ints[10]`.

Comment: If you need the address you don't care about overloaded operator[], and avoiding it is safer.

Answer (score 1):

More readable and more maintainable code is better code.

As for functional part... There is no difference. Both times you are "playing with memory".

Answer (score 1):

There is no functional difference. The decision to use either form is usually made depending on the context in which you are using it. Now in this example, the array form is simpler to use and read and hence is the obvious choice. However, suppose you were processing a character array, say, consuming the words in a sentence. Given a pointer to the array you might find it easier to use the second form as in the code snippet below:

```
int parse_line(char* line) 
{
    char* p = line;
    while(*p)
    {
         // consume
         p++;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit 1 : Decade-old question. But still, I think this answer will help to know the compiler's perspective.

Compiler creates the same machine code for both cases. here's a proof,

code 1

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int myArr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int value = myArr[0];

}
```

code 2

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int myArr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int value = *(myArr + 0);

}
```

Below is the result of the comparison done on assembly code generated by compiling the C code of both the codes with gcc -S.

[image: Here is the proof]

Answer (score -1):

Actually , When an Array 'a' is initialized a pointer to its first memory location ie.. a[0] is returned which is nothing but a ;

So if you do 'a+1' it is actually a pointer to a[1]

if you do 'a+2' it is actually a pointer to a[2]

if you do 'a+3' it is actually a pointer to a[3]
 so on ,

so if you do *(a+1) you will get value of a[1] and similar for other values also.
if you do *(a) you actually get a[0], 
So i think its pretty clear now how it works..