# Using *(pointer+i) versus pointer[i]

Tags: c++, pointers

Can somebody please explain this code

```
// Option 1
int **p = new Point*[2];
p[1] = new Point;
p[1]->x = p[1]->x = 1;

// Option 2
int **p = new Point*[2];
*(p+1) = new Point;
(*(p+1))->x = (*(p+1))->x = 1;
```

Isn't both options the same? Why when I create the variable using option 2, I cant write its value with option 1 (I got random numbers (address numbers?))? Is there any difference?

Comment: Yes, there's a difference; the second example never initialises y.

Comment: Well, for one thing you don't assign y to anything in Option 2 -- you do ->x twice.

Comment: Oh, I see you edited your example now so that both options have the same error.

Comment: The pseudo-code you have provided doesn't demonstrate the problem. Please create the smallest **actual** program that does demonstrate the problem and paste that program, in its entirety, into your question. See http://sscce.org/. (Hint: you should be able to demonstrate the problem in 10 lines or so.)

Comment: @Robᵩ the OP "demonstrates" the problem in the comment to CodeChordsman's answer below, by using some UB in printf.

Comment: @MrLister - I saw that, and you may be correct, but I came to a different conclusion than you. I concluded that the OP's actual problem is with a pointer to float and that he translated his code into the pseudocode seen above. (Since we know he didn't copy-paste what we see above, we can't know for sure what his real program looks like.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference Between \*(Pointer + Index) and Pointer\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622461/difference-between-pointer-index-and-pointer)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: `(*(p+1))->x = (*(p+1))->x = 1;` - should be `y` in the second term

Comment: sorry, there should by "x" as you have written. Im writing a project and I got different outputs on printf("%f != %f", p[1], *(p+1));

Comment: @Buksy Why are you using %f there? %f expects a double, not a pointer to a struct. _Of course_ it prints two different values!