# Difference between int (*ip)[4] with int ip[4]?

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there any difference between `int (*ip)[4]` and `int ip[4]` in C++?

Comment: Have you tried anything to see for yourself?

Comment: Look up similar questions about C and C++ declarations.

Comment: no, it is not int *ip[4] but int (*ip)[4]

Comment: Is there a difference between an `array of ints` and a `pointer to an array of ints`. Most likely, yes. However, why have you posted the question thrice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference Between \*(Pointer + Index) and Pointer\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622461/difference-between-pointer-index-and-pointer)

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any difference between `int (*ip)[4]` and `int ip[4]` in C++?

Yes, `int (*a)[4]` is a pointer to an array of 4 integers while `int b[4]` is an array of 4 integers. Note that `a` is not an array, it's simply a pointer. Here is an example:

```
int main()
{
    int a[5] = {2, 3, 6, 8, 10};
    int (*b)[5] = &a; // assign the address of the array to the pointer

    b[2] = 4; // dereferences the pointer and assigns a[2] to 4
}
```

Another difference is that you can pass a pointer to an array as a parameter to a function without it having to undergo array-to-pointer conversion.

```
void f( int (*array)[5] ); // must have a size of 5

int main()
{
    int a[10],
        b[5];

    f(&a); // NO
    f(&b); // Okay
}
```

You can avoid passing the address by using a *reference* to an array. It has the same semantics as a normal reference, so you can simply substitute `*` with `&` in the signature. And you would instead do `f(a)` and `f(b)`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `int (*ip)[4]` with `int ip[4]` is the same as the difference between, say, `int i` and `int *i`. And in general, it is the same as the difference between `T t` and `T *t` for any type `T`. I.e. the former declares an *object* of some type `T`, while the latter declares a *pointer to an object* of type `T`.

It is non-obvious from the syntax, but it is the case. To illustrate it further, these your original declarations

```
int (*ip1)[4];
int ip2[4];
```

can be replaced with the following sequence

```
typedef int FourIntsArray[4];

FourIntsArray *ip1; // <- same as `int (*ip1)[4]`
FourIntsArray ip2;  // <- same as `int ip2[4]`
```

The latter declarations are exactly equivalent to your original declarations.