# Understand how this double becomes an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

So I'm currently reading and learning a code from the internet (related to artificial neural network) and I found a part of the code that I don't understand why it works.

```
double* inputNeurons;
double* hiddenNeurons;
double* outputNeurons;
```

This is how it was declared. Then in this next code, it was changed and used as an array?

```
inputNeurons = new( double[in + 1] );
for ( int i=0; i < in; i++ ) inputNeurons[i] = 0;

inputNeurons[in] = -1; // 'in' is declared in the function as an int
```

So, I want to understand why and how it works. Did it become an array of "doubles"? If so, in what way can I also use this? Can this be used for struct or even class?

Comment: The code looks like it has a bug in it. But syntactically, pointers can be indexed just like arrays. This can be quite handy if they point to an element in an array.

Comment: The code works, as I compiled it and tested what it does.

Comment: See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622461/difference-between-pointer-index-and-pointer)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I misread the position of the parentheses in `inputNeurons = new( double[in + 1] );`

Comment: I hope the allocated memory was destroyed later on in the code (delete [ ])

Comment: It is, there's a constructor and destructor

Comment: `for( int i = 0; i < in; i ++ ) inputNeurons[i] = 0;` would be better written as `memset(inputNeurons, 0, in);`

Comment: Also, if `-1` is a meant to be a sentinel value, it would be better to store the *length* of the array instead. Either as the first element (size preceding data), or by combining the array and its length in a structure/class. I think that's where vectors come in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every array can be treated as a pointer. But that does not mean every pointer is an array. Do not mix this up!

Assuming we have an array `int test[..]`, the variable name also represents the address where the array is stored in the memory. So you could write

```
int * p = test;
```

At that moment my pointer `p` "becomes" an array, where "becomes" means 'points to an array'. Your example is similar - the only difference is that the memory is allocated dynamically (heap) and not on the stack (as in my example).

So how are the elements accessed?
Let's say, we want to get the first element (index 0).
We could say

```
int i = test[0];
```

or we could say

```
int i = *p;
```

Now we want to get the element at index 1:

```
int i = test[1];
```

Or - by using pointer arithmetics we could write

```
int i = *(p + 1);
```

Comment: That memory isn't allocated statically in your example. It's allocated automatically.

Comment: It's created on the stack. But yeah, static was probably a poor description.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ (and C) pointers support indexing operator `[]` which basically adjusts the value of the pointer by the amount specified times the size of the type pointed.

So basically

```
inputNeurons[5] = 0;
```

is equivalent to

```
*(inputNeurons+5) = 0
```

Now this doesn't give you any guarantee about the fact that `inputNeurons` points to an address which is correctly allocated to store at least 6 `double` values but syntactically it is correct and well defined.

You are just adjusting an address to point to the i-th element of a given type starting from the specified address.

This means that

```
double x;
double* px = &x;
px[5] = 0;
```

Is syntactically correct although it is wrong, since `px+5` is an address which points to memory which has not been reserved correctly to hold that value.

Comment: I'd say your example is equivalent to `inputNeurons+5`, without that sizeof part

Comment: Can this be used for structs and class too?

Like

myStruct* neurons;
neurons = new(myStruct[5]);

and have 5 myStructs that can be accessed with [0]...[4]?

Comment: Yes, correct syntax is `myStruct* neurons = new myStruct[5];` but mind that you are working in C++ so a `vector<mySruct>` could be a better solution. Don't foget that with `new` you need `delete` and if you are allocating an array you __must__ use `delete [] neurons` since the compiler can't figure out that the pointed data is indeed an array and not just a single value.

Comment: @Jeremy Yes, it works for all default constructable types. But the parentheses make it look confusing. The usual syntax is `T* a = new T[N];`

Comment: vector? I'll try to look it up, thanks for the suggestion man

Comment: Using a `std::vector<T>` will help you since it automatically grows as need and it manages memory automatically (so you don't need `new` and `delete` at all).

Answer (score 0):

The pointer of type `double` (`double* inputNeurons;`) just gets assigned to point to the beginning of an dynamically allocated array (`new( double[in + 1]`)) of the same type. It does not become an array.

You can do this with any other pointer and regular array of the same type. As a matter of fact an array is a pointer to specific address (to its beginning, i.e. to the element with index: 0).

When you increment the pointer by + 1, that one means `1 * type_size` (i.e `1 * size_of_double`)

In your case: `inputNeurons` points to the address of the first element of the array. If you dereference it: `*inputNeurons`, you will get the value stored at that address (if `inputNeurons` was an array, it would be equivalent to: `inputNeurons[0]` ).
 To access the next element just increment by one `(*inputNeurons + 1)`.