# Various ways of array representation using pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was experimenting with array and pointers in C. And here

http://r4r.co.in/c/c_topics/c_array_basics/array_representation_in_memory.shtml

I read that

```
ar[2]=*(ar+(sizeof(datatype)*2));
```

However after writing following test program in C:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int array[]={10,11,12,13,14};

    printf("\nArray:%d",array);
    printf("\nArray+4:%p",array+4);
    printf("\nArray+(sizeof(int)*4):%p",array+((sizeof(int))*4));
    printf("\n*(Array+4):%d",*(array+4));
    printf("\n*(Array+(sizeof(int)*4)):%d",*(array+((sizeof(int))*4)));

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I get following output:-

```
Array:2686700
Array+4:0028FEFC
Array+(sizeof(int)*4):0028FF2C
*(Array+4):14
*(Array+(sizeof(int)*4)):4214784
```

So from here I concluded that the expression

```
array[4]=*(array+(sizeof(int)*4));
```

is not working rather expression

```
array[4]=*(array+4);
```

is true.

So is my conclusion right or wrong? If it is wrong then why is that so?

Language:-C
Version:-gcc (tdm-1) 4.7.1
Platform:-Windows 8.1

Edit:
1). Changed following lines:
`((sizeof(int*))*4` to `((sizeof(int))*4`
2). Changed title to : Various ways of array representation using pointers in C.
3). Fixed grammar.

Comment: Note the datatype of `array`. Pointer aritmatic involves the data type of the pointer. and please, use `%p` for printing pointers.

Comment: Yes, for any array (or pointer) `a` and index `i` the expression `a[i]` is exactly the same as `*(a + i)`. It's even in the C specification.

Comment: The why it is written at some places that ar[2]=*(ar+(sizeof(datatype)*2));. Is that wrong.Please Explain

Comment: `ar[2]=*(ar+(sizeof(datatype)*2));` vs. `array[2]=*(array+(sizeof(int)*4));`: Why do you use `2`in the 1st snippet and `4` in the second? Typo or intention? :-S

Comment: Please try next asset : `*((char *)array+((sizeof(int*))*4)))` and `*(int *)((char *)array+((sizeof(int*))*4)))`

The idea is that when you add some value to pointer it doesn't add addresses. It just re-position to element X of datasize according to pointer type

Comment: @alk sorry it my mistake I am correcting it

Comment: OT: To print a pointer value use `p` and only `p`, not `d`.

Comment: Pointer arithmetics: Incrementing a pointer of type `T` by `N` increments the pointer by `N * sizeof (T)` bytes. `void`-pointer may not be operands to this arithmetics.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/232303/694576

Comment: @ George Gaál Thanks for you comment.Now I understand it clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`E1[E2]` is defined to be equivalent to `*((E1)+(E2))` ([N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.5.2.1), so `array[4]` will always be `*(array+4)` given that it is in valid range.

`+` operator used between a pointer to integer is defined to give (the integer) *elements* (not bytes) after what is pointerd by the pointer. (N1570 6.5.6), so `*(array+(sizeof(int)*4))` will be out-of-range if `sizeof(int) >= 2` and moving pointer to out-of-range will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Also note that you should use correct format specifiers for `printf()`, or you will invoke *undefined behavior*.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[]={10,11,12,13,14};

    printf("\nArray:%p",(void*)array);
    printf("\nArray+4:%p",(void*)(array+4));
    printf("\nArray+(sizeof(int)*4):%p",(void*)(array+((sizeof(int*))*4))); /* maybe undefined behavior */
    printf("\n*(Array+4):%d",*(array+4));
    printf("\n*(Array+(sizeof(int)*4)):%d",*(array+((sizeof(int*))*4))); /* maybe undefined behavior */

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You originally misinterpreted the way addition works with pointers. A pointer is an address plus the type of object it points to. So, addition knows that it has to add `sizeof()` bytes.

See
[Difference Between *(Pointer + Index) and Pointer[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622461/difference-between-pointer-index-and-pointer)
and 
[this](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html).

Plus, in statement

```
printf("\nArray+(sizeof(int)*4):%p",array+((sizeof(int*))*4));
```

you are actually using `sizeof(int*)` instead of `sizeof(int)`.
Likewise in another line. So, you are not printing what you think you are.

Note also the [interesting facts about commutation](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html).

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic takes the size of the pointed-to type into account.  Given a pointer `p` to an object of type `T`, the expression `p+1` will give the address of the next object of type `T`.  So, if `p == 0x8000`, `p+1` may yield `0x8001`, `0x8002`, `0x8004`, `0x8008`, or any other value depending on the size of `T`.

Thus, `a[i] == *(a + i)`; given an address `a`, offset `i` *elements* (**not bytes**) from that address and dereference the result.  You do not need to multiply the offset by the size of the pointed-to type.

Answer (score 0):

```
 printf("\n*(Array+(sizeof(int)*4)):%d",*(array+((sizeof(int*))*4)));
```

should be

```
printf("\n*(Array+(sizeof(int)*4)):%d",*(array+((sizeof(int))*4)));
```

and the above is only valid when the array of int is treated each byte, which i think is unlikely.