# Unix Read Buffer Parameter

Tags: c++, unix, raspberry-pi, spi

I have a Raspberry-pi 3 which I am trying to interface with FLIR Lepton thermal camera.  While I understand how this interface works, I have a question regarding the SPI `read` command.  Below is the snippet of the code.  Full source can be found at [github](https://github.com/groupgets/LeptonModule/blob/master/software/raspberrypi_video/LeptonThread.cpp)

```
#define PACKET_SIZE 164
#define PACKET_SIZE_UINT16 (PACKET_SIZE/2)  //82
#define PACKETS_PER_FRAME 60
#define FRAME_SIZE_UINT16 (PACKET_SIZE_UINT16*PACKETS_PER_FRAME)  //4920

uint8_t result[PACKET_SIZE*PACKETS_PER_FRAME];  //9840

for(int j=0;j<PACKETS_PER_FRAME;j++) {
    read(spi_cs0_fd, result+sizeof(uint8_t)*PACKET_SIZE*j, sizeof(uint8_t)*PACKET_SIZE);
}
```

Since the second parameter of the unix `read` call is the buffer `void *buf`, I cannot figure out how the parameter `result+sizeof(uint8_t)*PACKET_SIZE*j` resolves into a pointer of a location in the array `result`.

Can someone help explain how this resolves into an array location in `result`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result+sizeof(uint8_t)*PACKET_SIZE*j` is same as `&result[PACKET_SIZE*j]`, which address of memory location at the index `PACKET_SIZE * j` in `result` array.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4622461/1870232)

Answer (score 1):

imagine your array is allocated in memory as the following

```
packet 0:
  [0]
  ..
  [163]
packet 1:
  [164]
  ..
  [227]
packet 2:
  [228]
   ...
```

so, address of packet 1 is (size of the packet (164) * j(1)), where j is the packet number.
sizeof unit8 will resolve in the number of bytes needed, '1' in most cases.