# Passing pointers to other function creating segmentaion fault

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, double-pointer

> ```
>  struct temp {
>      int a;
>  };
>  int pass(struct temp **); //passing var
>  int pass(struct temp ** var1) { //passing var
>      (* var1)->a = 100;
>      return 0;
>  };
>  int main() {
>      struct temp * var2 = NULL;
>      var2->a = 10;
>      printf("\nbefore pass var2->a = %d", var2->a);
>      pass(&var2);
>      printf("\nafter pass var2->a = %d", var2->a); 
>      return 0;
>  }
> ```

bash$ !gc
gcc sample2.c ; ./a.exe
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I am trying to update a's value inside the pass() function but keep getting seg fault. Not sure as to what's going wrong. Looking for the rectified code! TIA!

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
 struct temp * var2 = NULL;
```

you create a pointer to `struct temp` and initialize it to NULL. It is **only** a pointer - there is **not** any memory for a `struct temp`.

Then you do:

```
var2->a = 10;
```

which means you dereference a NULL pointer. That will fail.

Try this:

```
struct temp * var2 = malloc(sizeof *var2);  // Create pointer and allocate 
                                            // memory for a struct temp
```

instead.

BTW: You don't need to pass double-pointer to the function. Just `int pass(struct temp *);` will do.

So the complete code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 struct temp {
     int a;
 };

 int pass(struct temp *); //passing var
 int pass(struct temp * var1) { //passing var
     var1->a = 100;
     return 0;
 };

 int main() {
     struct temp * var2 = malloc(sizeof *var2);
     var2->a = 10;
     printf("\nbefore pass var2->a = %d", var2->a);
     pass(var2);
     printf("\nafter pass var2->a = %d", var2->a); 
     free(var2);
     return 0;
 }
```

Passing a double pointer in code like this is only needed if you want to change the value of `var2` in main. For instance if the function should allocate more memory (i.e. more `struct temp` elements).

It could be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 struct temp {
     int a;
 };

 int pass(struct temp **);
 int pass(struct temp ** var1) {
     free(*var1);                         // Free previous allocation
     *var1 = malloc(20 * sizeof **var1);  // Allocate 20 struct temp
     (*var1)[0].a = 100;
     (*var1)[1].a = 200;
     return 0;
 };

 int main() {
     struct temp * var2 = malloc(sizeof *var2);  // Allocate 1 struct temp
     var2->a = 10;
     printf("\npointer before pass var2 = %p", (void*)var2);
     printf("\nbefore pass var2[0].a = %d", var2[0].a);
     // printf("\nbefore pass var2[1].a = %d", var2[1].a);  // ILLEGAL HERE

     pass(&var2);

     printf("\npointer after pass var2 = %p", (void*)var2);
     printf("\nafter pass var2[0].a = %d", var2[0].a); 
     printf("\nafter pass var2[1].a = %d", var2[1].a);   // LEGAL HERE

     free(var2);
     return 0;
 }
```

Possible output:

```
pointer before pass var2 = 0x563d28afa010
before pass var2[0].a = 10
pointer after pass var2 = 0x563d28afb040
after pass var2[0].a = 100
after pass var2[1].a = 200
```

Notice how the value of the pointer changed.

Comment: Ok so the issue was missing heap memory allocation was.
Thanks.
But I am learning familiarize with passing using double pointers so please explain in that context.

Comment: Thanks. Just what I wanted.
One last query.

printf("\nbefore pass var2[0].a = %d", var2[0].a);  <-----
Are the pointer variables and arrays interrelated? Any specific reason why you used "[0]" or is it just an alternate form. I was able to run your code with "var[2]->a".

Comment: @kmP You ask: "Are the pointer variables and arrays interrelated?" Well, yes. Wrinting: `*somePointer` is the same as `somePointer[0]` and writing `*(somePointer + 5)` is the same as `somePointer[5]` Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622461/difference-between-pointer-index-and-pointer

Answer (score 0):

In main you are doing `var = NULL;` and in the next line you do `var2->a = 10;` which means you are trying to assign a value to structure pointed by `var`, but var is not pointing to any structure as of yet.

Perhaps what you want to do is:

```
 struct temp {
     int a;
 };
 int pass(struct temp *); //passing var
 int pass(struct temp * var1) { //passing var
     var1->a = 100;
     return 0;
 };
 int main() {
     struct temp var2;
     var2.a = 10;
     printf("\nbefore pass var2->a = %d", var2.a);
     pass(&var2);
     printf("\nafter pass var2->a = %d", var2.a); 
     return 0;
 }
```