# Allocating and constructing 5 objects

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code that allocates and creates 5 objects of type MyClass:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <new>             
struct MyClass {
  int data;

};

int main () {

  struct MyClass *p1=new MyClass[5];
  p1->data=42;

  return 0;
}
```

So,if i understand this correctly p1 is a pointer to a memory location of size Myclass[5] where these 5 objects are stored.So by using p1->data=42 is the int data updated for each of 5 objects.If so,how can i update data individually for a specific object?(Let's say the 3rd one)

Comment: `p1->data` applies to the first object only. You want `p1[i].data`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat p1[2].data=4; is possible even if p1 is a pointer?

Comment: Hi @Epitheoritis 32, p1 is a pointer the bracket [dereferences the pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622461/difference-between-pointer-index-and-pointer) so you can treat is like an object.

Comment: @Epitheoritis32 Yes. In fact, it *only* works on pointers (if we don't consider overloaded operators). When you apply it to an array, the array is converted to a pointer first.

Answer (score 3):

Update:
If you allocate yourself, as HolyBlackCat says:

```
p1[i].data = 42;
```

Bu if this is not an assignment and you don't have to use new...

```
#include <vector>
struct MyClass {
    int data;

};
using MyClassVect_type = std::vector<MyClass>;

int main() {

    MyClassVect_type my_5(5);

    my_5.at(0).data = 37;
    my_5.at(1).data = 42;
    //or
    my_5[2].data = 13;
    //etc....

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you at least answer the question first?

Answer (score 2):

> So by using `p1->data=42` is the `int` data updated for each of 5 objects.

Incorrect. `p1` points to the first of those 5 objects. So, `p1->data=42` assigns only the member of the first object.

> how can i update data individually for a specific object?

You can use the subscript operator to access the sibling objects: `p1[i].data = 42` assigns the member of the `i`th object in the array.

---

P.S. The example program leaks the allocated memory.

P.P.S. It is not necessary to include the header `<new>` in order to use the `new`-expression.

Comment: What do you mean by saying leaks the allocated memory?

Comment: @Epitheoritis32 Objects created using a `new`-expression are not automatically destroyed. They must be explicitly `delete`d. If the pointer returned by `new` is lost before the object is deleted through it, it can never be deleted. This is called a memory leak.