# Adding index to array leads to array shift in C++

Tags: c++

I'm working with some C++, and I'd like to understand why the following works.

I have an index:

```
long long I;
```

And an array:

```
double *arr = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*100);
```

It looks like `arr + I` shifts the index of `arr`. So, for example, if `I=1` then the outcome of this line is `arr[1:]`.  Why is this?

Also, if I have an array of arrays (ex below), what should the shape of `I` be?

```
double **arr = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double *)*2);
for (k = 0; k < num_time_series; k++) {
    arr[k] = (double*) malloc(100 * sizeof(double));
```

Comment: For any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`. From that follows that `p + i` is a pointer to the element with index `i`, i.e `p + i` is equal to `&p[i]`.

Comment: And the "array of arrays" you have *isn't* an array of arrays, it's a pointer to the first element of what could be an array, where each element in turn is a pointer. It's commonly called a [*jagged* array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

Comment: Alright, thanks! So how do I perform *(p+i) for a jagged array?

Comment: Exactly the same. For your `arr` if you want to use `arr[i][j]` that's `*(*(arr + i) + j)`.

Comment: Yes but I would like to shift all the subarrays at once using j.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Well you can't.  You could build another table of pointers, where `shifted[i] = arr[i] + j forall i`, but since the actual contents aren't stored sequentially, there's no way for pointer math to find them all at once.  Another option would be to return a proxy object that knows to add an offset (or any other mapping of your choice) when its `operator[]` is invoked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference Between \*(Pointer + Index) and Pointer\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622461/difference-between-pointer-index-and-pointer)