# How to modify an array inside a function in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

Let's consider the following example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change_byte(int *byte);

int main()
{
    int byte = 0;
    change_byte(&byte);
    printf("Byte : %d \r\n", byte);
}

void change_byte(int *byte)
{
    *byte= 5;
}
```

I am simply changing the value of an integer inside a function by passing the integer as a pointer to the function. It yields :

```
Byte : 5
```

Everything's fine.

---

I want to generalize the function to modify an array of integer instead of an integer. Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE_ARRAY 10

void change_array(int *array, int size);

int main()
{
    int array[SIZE_ARRAY] = {0};
    change_array(array, SIZE_ARRAY);
    
    printf("Array : ");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < SIZE_ARRAY ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}

void change_array(int *array, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 5;
    }
}
```

It yields :

```
Array : 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

I like it because it does not make use of dynamic allocation, but I have trouble understand how it works. From what I understand, array gets converted into a pointer when entering the function change_array. But when I was changing the value of byte in the previous example, I was doing *byte = 5. Here, I am doing array[i] = 5 and not *array[i] = 5.

---

Finally, I want to change the previous example to modify array based on a global array :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE_ARRAY 10

int global_array[10] = {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5};

void change_array(int *array, int size);

int main()
{
    int array[SIZE_ARRAY] = {0};
    change_array(array, SIZE_ARRAY);
    
    printf("Array : ");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < SIZE_ARRAY ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}

void change_array(int *array, int size)
{
    array = global_array;
}
```

It yields :

```
Array : 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Why is it so ? What to I need to change to make it work ?

Thanks.

Comment: A few links that provide basic discussions of pointers may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102) (ignore the titles, the answers discuss pointer basics) For your last example: `array = global_array;` Arrays are NOT assignaable. (not an lvalue), You are assigning the address of `global_array` to the local pointer `array` which goes out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: Of possible interest: Difference Between `*(Pointer + Index)` and `Pointer[]` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622461/difference-between-pointer-index-and-pointer). Your `*array[i] = 5` is incorrect.

Comment: `*byte` is the same as `byte[0]`, likewise `a[0]` is the same as `*a` ... and, generally, `a[i]` is the same as `*(a + i)`. These are just different ways to write **the same thing**.

Comment: All of these questions can and should be answered by reading a C programming book. You aren't doing yourself a favour fiddling around with trial & error without understanding what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your first program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change_byte(int *byte);

int main()
{
    int byte = 0;
    change_byte(&byte);
    printf("Byte : %d \r\n", byte);
}

void change_byte(int *byte)
{
    *byte= 5;
}
```

In this program the object `byte` is passed to the function `change_byte` by reference through a pointer to it

```
change_byte(&byte);
```

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer tp it.

So dereferencing the pointer `byte` declared as a function parameter

```
void change_byte(int *byte);
```

you get a direct access to the pointed object `byte` of the type `int` defined in main.

Now let's consider your second program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE_ARRAY 10

void change_array(int *array, int size);

int main()
{
    int array[SIZE_ARRAY] = {0};
    change_array(array, SIZE_ARRAY);
    
    printf("Array : ");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < SIZE_ARRAY ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}

void change_array(int *array, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 5;
    }
}
```

In main you declared an integer array

```
int array[SIZE_ARRAY] = {0};
```

Array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

Thus this call

```
change_array(array, SIZE_ARRAY);
```

is equivalent to

```
change_array( &array[0], SIZE_ARRAY);
```

So dereferencing the pointer within the function you can change the first element of the array defined in main.

But array elements are stored in a continuous extent of memory. So using the pointer arithmetic and having a pointer to the first element of an array you can access all elements of the array.

In fact all elements of the array `array` are passed to the function `change_array` by reference through a pointer to the first element of the array.

For example the for loop within the function you could rewrite like

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        *( array + i ) = 5;
    }
```

Now let's consider your third program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE_ARRAY 10

int global_array[10] = {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5};

void change_array(int *array, int size);

int main()
{
    int array[SIZE_ARRAY] = {0};
    change_array(array, SIZE_ARRAY);
    
    printf("Array : ");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < SIZE_ARRAY ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}

void change_array(int *array, int size)
{
    array = global_array;
}
```

As it was pointed out already the array `array` passed to the function `change_array` is converted to a pointer to its first element.

You may imagine the function call and its definition the following way (I will rename the first function parameter that to avoid name ambiguity).

```
change_array(array, SIZE_ARRAY);

//...

void change_array( /* int *parm_array, int size */)
{
    int * parm_array = array;
    int size = SIZE_ARRAY;

    parm_array = global_array;
}
```

That is function parameters are its local variables. The parameter `parm_array` is alive until the function stops its execution.

Thus this statement

```
    parm_array = global_array;
```

assign the pointer to the first element of the global array `global_array` to the local variable `parm_array` of the function. This assignment does not touch in any way the array `array` defined in main. It only changes the local variable `parm_array` declared in the function `change_array`.

To achieve the expected by you result you could define in main a pointer that is initialized by the array `array`. And in the function `change_array` you could reassigned the pointer with the array `global_array` passing it to the function by reference the same way as you passed the object `byte` in your first program.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE_ARRAY 10

int global_array[10] = {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5};

void change_array( int **array_ptr );

int main()
{
    int array[SIZE_ARRAY] = {0};
    int *array_ptr = array;
    
    change_array( &array_ptr );
    
    printf("Array : ");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < SIZE_ARRAY ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array_ptr[i]);
    }
}

void change_array( int **array_ptr )
{
    *array_ptr = global_array;
}
```

The program output is'

```
Array : 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now everything's clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

For a better understanding (and exercise), edit your function

```
void change_array(int *array, int size)
{
    array = global_array;
}
```

to

```
void change_array(int *array, int size)
{
    array = global_array;
    for (int i=0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
}
```

Ask yourself, what the output 'means'.