# What does array index operator do on an object if not overloaded?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm writting Matrix class and got to the point where I need to create an array of Array objects, but Array can't have constructor with no arguments ( it need m argument to allocate memory for it ). I searched and haven't found the solution, people only sugest doing it with Vector object, but I am not allowed to do it with anything other than arrays. Then a friend sent me the constructor for matrix that works for them, but even they don't know why it works.

```
Matrix::Matrix(int n, int m):n(n),m(m) {
    srand(time(0));
    this->data=new Array(n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        this->data[i].m=this->m;
        this->data[i].data=new int[m];
        for(int j=0; j<this->m; j++){
            this->data[i].data[j]= rand()%10; 
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get how this `this->data[i]` is defined? [] operator isn't overloaded anywhere and data is only a single Array object not an array of Array-s. So why and how is this working and not an compile error?

Source files:

Header:

````
#define ROK04_ROK04_H

class Array{
protected:
    int* data;
    int m;

public:
    Array(int m);
    Array& operator = (const Array& a);
    virtual ~Array();
    Array& operator+=(const Array& a);
    virtual void setElem(int pos, int value);
    virtual void print() const;
    friend class Matrix;
};

class Matrix{
protected:
    Array* data;
    int n;
    int m;
public:
    Matrix(int n, int m);
};

#endif //ROK04_ROK04_H ```

#ifndef ROK04_ROK04_H
#define ROK04_ROK04_H

class Array{
protected:
    int* data;
    int m;

public:
    Array(int m);
    Array& operator = (const Array& a);
    virtual ~Array();
    Array& operator+=(const Array& a);
    virtual void setElem(int pos, int value);
    virtual void stampa() const;
    friend class Matrix;
};

class Matrix{
protected:
    Array* data;
    int n;
    int m;
public:
    Matrix(int n, int m);
    void stampaj();

};

#endif //ROK04_ROK04_H
````

Cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "rok04.h"
using namespace std;

Array::Array(int m):m(m),data( new int[m]() ){}

Array& Array::operator=(const Array& a) {
    cout << "Usao" << this << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        data[i] = a.data[i];
    }

    return *this;
}

Array::~Array() {
    delete[] data;
}

void Array::setElem(int pos, int value) {
    try {

        if(pos >= m){
            cout << "Usao\n";
            throw out_of_range("Index out of bounds!");
        }

        data[pos] = value;

    } catch (out_of_range& oor){
        cerr << oor.what() << endl;
    }
}

void Array::print() const {
//    cout << m;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        cout << data[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

Array &Array::operator+=(const Array& a) {

    int* temp = new int(m+a.m);

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        temp[i] = data[i];
    }

    for (int i = m; i < m+a.m; ++i) {
        temp[i] = a.data[i-m];
    }

    delete[] data;
    data = temp;
    m = m+a.m;

    return *this;
}

Matrix::Matrix(int n, int m):n(n),m(m) {
    srand(time(0));
    this->data=new Array(n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        this->data[i].m=this->m;
        this->data[i].data=new int[m];
        for(int j=0; j<this->m; j++){
            this->data[i].data[j]= rand()%10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `this->data` is not an object of class type - it's a pointer to `Array`. `this->data[i]` uses the built-in `[]` operator - it accesses `i`th element in the (plain) array of `Array` objects that `data` points to. Except that `data` only actually points to a single object, so `this->data[i]` exhibits undefined behavior whenever `i != 0`, by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: In this case, `this->data[i]` is performing **pointer arithmetic**, it is identical to `*(this->data + i)`

Comment: The constructor doesn't work. `this->data=new Array(n);` looks like a typo for `this->data=new Array[n];` which would create `n` objects of type `Array`, but `this->data=new Array(n);` creates only one. `this->data=new Array[n];` doesn't work for you though, since `Array` requires an argument for construction.

Comment: If you are expected to use only `new` and not the standard library, then the only easy way out of this is to define a default constructor for `Array` which initializes the pointer to `nullptr`, and then you can assign the actual fully constructed `Array` objects in a loop.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622461/difference-between-pointer-index-and-pointer

Comment: No, the shown code definitely doesn't work. It might compile, but it will not work. Your "friend"'s belief that their code works, for some strange reason, it's incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this definition: `int* data`. So [by default](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access), given a pointer operand, `data[x]` is translated into `*(data  + x)` by the C++ compiler.